# Parent class accessing protected members of subclasses Java

Tags: java, subclass, protected

I have the following code which I think is not totally explained by Oracle's tutorials.

```
package visibilidad;

import otropaquete.*;

public class ejemplo2 extends Test {
    protected int prot = 4;
}



package otropaquete;

import visibilidad.*;

public class Test {
    public void metodopublico() {
        ejemplo2 a = new ejemplo2();
        System.out.println(a.prot);
        Hija b = new Hija();
        System.out.println(b.prot);
    }
}

class Hija extends Test {
    protected int prot = 3;
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to access a protected member of subclasses from the parent class. The funny thing is that this gives a compile time error when the subclass is defined in another package and it 
runs perfectly if the subclass is defined in the same class.

I would like to know if this behaviour is considered in the standard or not.

Comment: It's obviously standard if you get a compile time error, no?

Comment: yes, but the compile time error reads as generic as "prot has protected access in ejemplo2". i mean if this was considered or just left random

Comment: Yes protected variables can only be accessed from within the same package.

Comment: Visible to the package and all subclasses (protected).

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Java` there are 4 different access modifiers:

> (No Modifier) - Visible to the package.
>
> (private) - Visible to the class only.
>
> (public) - Visible to the world.
>
> (protected) - Visible to the package and all subclasses.

Here is a [reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm)

Using the `protected` modifier means only other `classes` of that package and `subclasses` can access the field/method. In your case the class from the same package works fine and the one from a different package throws compile time error which is exactly what is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 4):

[The docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) are very explicit: `protected` fields are accessible in the Class, Package and Subclass level. Since the parent is neither a subclass nor inside the same package - the field is not accessible and you're getting a compilation error.

The access-levels table from Oracle docs:

```
               Access Levels
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public      Y       Y       Y           Y
protected   Y       Y       Y           N
no modifier Y       Y       N           N
private     Y       N       N           N
```

Answer (score 0):

The `protected` modifier allows access from the same package as well. See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).